# What is the default type search done by google, while, processing a query

Tags: google

What is the default type search done by google, while, processing a query. Does it do 'broad' 'phrase' or 'exact' match searches?

Answer (score 4):

It's not really that simple when you factor in personalization, Google's tendency to use synonyms or "corrected" spellings rather than what you actually tell it, etc. but here's Google [basic search help page](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1221265&answer=134479&rd=1) with a quick overview of how it treats your terms. Phrase searching is [triggered with quotes](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1221265&answer=136861&rd=1#exceptions). You'll have to explain how that's different from "exact" searches.

Reading all of that page will probably answer several other questions you likely have.